# YouTube API, defining as a class & stopping a video

Tags: javascript, api, video, youtube

I'm building a site based on anchor points and Jquery with different slides for each page (it's all working well, just thought i'd give some background)

Now, here's the thing. On three of the slides there are Youtube videos that need to automatically stop when navigated away from. So I have written in 'Back' buttons with the following string attached

```
onclick="player.stopVideo(); return false"
```

Now the issue i'm having is that Youtube API automatically gives the player the id of 'player' and not a class, with this line of code called in after the API

```
<script>
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {player = new YT.Player('player');} 
</script>
```

And an iframe like this

```
<iframe id="player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TMFINFk_080?&vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Works perfectly, as expected.
Now, I need this as a class as I have multiple videos that need to have that stop line applied to them on the same page, and i'm totally lost. A friend suggested defining a function to call the stop command to anything with a class name, but I have no idea where to start there.

Thanks.

As a note: Iframe would be ideal as there is a lot of code on this page already and adding embeds will take up more space, not too fussed on this but the support that iframe offers is ideal

Answer (score 0):

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {player = new YT.Player('player');}
if(window.opera){
    addEventListener('load', onYouTubeIframeAPIReady, false);
}
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 });
</script>
<div id="video">
  <iframe id="player" width="560" height="349" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vE_0V55Vywc?rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
</div>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player.playVideo(); return false">play</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player.stopVideo(); return false">stop</a>
</body>
</html>
```

`exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/ckWLs/1/